# ie8 div jumps after page load

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following setup. 1 column with a left floated inner column and a right floated inner column. Works very well on firefox. IE does something strange.

I have parts in the left column that is loaded from weather.co.za with javascript. The right column has an ad loaded and displayed with jQuery.

On initial load everything is fine. Right column displays as it should. As soon as the javascript in the left column or right column displays the content the right column "jumps" 10px to the left.

I have checked and do not seem to find any code that would cause the jump.

I am still learning as I go along, please help!

Comment: Are you attaching a margin in the same direction as the float? If not can u shade more light please.

Comment: we really need to see either a sample page or some sample code

Answer (score 1):

Had  margin-left:10px. changed that to padding-left:10px; now it is working!

Answer (score 0):

In my case ([trying in IE 7](https://twitter.com/johnleniel/status/405715275318038528)) I had to change:

```
margin-left: 6.35em;
```

to

```
margin-left: 90px;
```

`em` to `px`... doing so no more jumping happens after page load. IE is really really bad!